# Will the "small angle approximation" fail if you write < and > instead of ≤ and ≥?

Tags: geometry, limits, inequality, trigonometry

We had an exam where we essentially had to prove the famous geometric proof of the "small angle approximation". The problem had stated the inequality of the areas beforehand, and the task was to show how this enequality comes up. however, the inequality was stated as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sin(v) > \frac{v}{2} > \frac{1}{2} \tan(v).$$

This can after some simple algebra and trigonometry be changed to:

$$1>\frac{\sin v}{v}>\cos v$$

But when i see this equation online they use $≥$ and $≤$. at larger scales the inequality which used $<$ and $>$ made sense, as the areas were not equal, but at smaller scales, they can be equal, which is (I'm assuming) The basis for using $≥$ and $≤$ instead of just $<$ and $>$.

However, as i see it, this isn't just a small detail, but breaks the problem, which is where I am confused. If we from here try to solve the limit as $v$ is approaching $0$ from the positive side ($0+$), then we will get:

$$1>\frac{\sin0+}{0+}>1$$

In the case of "$≥$ and $≤$" the answer will make sense, as it can only be one. However, the answer above doesn't make sense to me. the "$1$" on the left side should be a true $1$, but the "$1$" on the right is a limit to "$1$" so technically just approaching $1$. then the answer would have to be just lower than $1$. Even in the solution-video, the teacher just sort of glossed over this and basically wrote that we should just say that this equals $1$.

This might be a little convoluted, as it's strange to think of $1$'s as not true $1$'s and stuff, but what i would like to know is **if the question/problem was poorly written**, or if $b > a > b \iff a = b$ is something we have defined in Math.

Comment: If you take limits in strict inequalities, you have to replace $<, >$ by $\le, \ge$. Consider for instance $\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\ge 2$. This is certainly true. What happens if you let $n\to +\infty$?

Comment: $b<a<b$??? This is not undefined. This is a contradiction and can never be achieved

Comment: To iraeVid: Thats what i thought, and that's why i posted this question as that seemed to the extent of my knowledge of math too flimsy, but that is the answer which we ended up with in our exam (also on the solution by the teachers), which is why i was confused and tried to find answers online, where i found that most people used ≥ instead, so I was wondering if this question was poorly written or if there were some other factors at play.

Comment: To Gary : Ah ok, that was very helpful, thanks! Also thanks to @IraeVid for cleaning up the question.

Comment: Though you've realized the overall issue here, your post also demonstrates a common misunderstanding of limits that has not been addressed. When talking about a limit of $1$, we are not talking about some nebulous concept of "approaching $1$". The "$1$" means exactly the number $1$. Limits are about what value functions approach at certain points, but limit itself is not the "approach". It is the value that is being approached. so in $1>\frac{\sin0+}{0+}>1$, the $1$ on the left and the $1$ on the right are both the "true $1$". The expression is just wrong, it should be $\ge$.